# NSOpenPanel, navigate to a connected iPad

Tags: macos, nsopenpanel

In a MacOs application, Is it possible to navigate to a connected iOS device?
I have a trusted iPad that I can see in the finder, however I cannot see it in my application using an NSOpenPanel.
Is it possible to do so?

```
@IBAction func selectLisaIngestPreviewFolder(_ sender: Any) {
    let openPanel = NSOpenPanel()
    openPanel.canChooseFiles = false
    openPanel.canChooseDirectories = true
    openPanel.message = "Select Lisa Preview folder"
    let response = openPanel.runModal()
    switch response.rawValue {
    case 1000:
        print(response.rawValue)
    case 1001:
        print(response.rawValue)
    default:
        return
    }
}
```

In the "locations" group of the panel I am able to see any connected drives however not connected devices.

I'm thinking it is this way for security reasons for distributed apps, however I'm wondering if there is a way to show connected devices for apps designed for internal use.